# Is there a way to determine if GWT code is running in development mode?

Tags: gwt, development-mode

I'm working on a GWT application and would like to branch some logic based on whether the code is running in development mode or is live in production.

For example, when the code needs to make an AJAX call we would like to set the URL depending on mode.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

GWT >= 2.1.0

```
boolean isDevelopmentMode() {
    return !GWT.isProdMode() && GWT.isClient();
}
```

GWT < 2.1.0

```
boolean isDevelopmentMode() {
    return !GWT.isScript() && GWT.isClient();
}
```

Comment: Note: added GWT.isClient() as otherwise this would be true for server side code.

Comment: I knew there was an easy way to determine this that was eluding me. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `!GWT.isProdMode()`?

Comment: @Sydney that was added in GWT after that answer was posted.

Answer (score 6):

```
boolean isProductionMode() {
  return GWT.isScript();
}

boolean isDevelopmentMode() {
  return !GWT.isScript() && GWT.isClient();
}

// e.g. JUnit tests
boolean isPlainJVM() {
  return !GWT.isClient();
}
```